# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid JSON expression: Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected token: ] @ line 1, column 36. weather[*].description

Tags: rest-assured

I am new to RestAssured and trying to the following code:

```
    @Test
        public void testJsonPath() {

        Response response = RestAssured

                .given()

                .param("id", "2172797")

                .param("appid", "439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02")

                .when()

                .get("https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather");

            String value = "weather[*].description";    

            System.out.println(value);

            String data = response.then().contentType(ContentType.JSON).extract().path(value);

            System.out.println(data);

        }

JSON:

{
  "coord": {
    "lon": 145.77,
    "lat": -16.92
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 802,
      "main": "Clouds",
      "description": "scattered clouds",
      "icon": "03n"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 300.15,
    "pressure": 1007,
    "humidity": 74,
    "temp_min": 300.15,
    "temp_max": 300.15
  },
  "visibility": 10000,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 3.6,
    "deg": 160
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 40
  },
  "dt": 1485790200,
  "sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 8166,
    "message": 0.2064,
    "country": "AU",
    "sunrise": 1485720272,
    "sunset": 1485766550
  },
  "id": 2172797,
  "name": "Cairns",
  "cod": 200
}

Getting the following error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid JSON expression:
Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected token: ] @ line 1, column 36.
                            weather[*].description
```

Why do we get the following error when using * ?. When replacing it String value = "weather[0].description"; it works fine. Can someone please help me with this.

I have checked the postman as well and the API is giving the correct output.

```
Note: When using creating code (weather[*].description) from http://jsonpath.com/. It gives the same output.

 If there is anything I am missing anything please let me know as I am new to it. Any help to this would be great.

It can also be great if someone can give me a brief on this and let me know whom to refer to get the best output from this.
```

Why do we get the following error when using * ?. When replacing it String value = "weather[0].description"; it works fine. Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: You should add some more tags so people can find your post and the code get's colored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rest Assured uses Groovy's GPath notation and is not to be confused with Jayway's JsonPath syntax

[Official Documentation](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#example-1---json)

[GPath](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_gpath)

[JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)

**Edit :**

> {"users":[{"firstName":"sijo","lastName":"john","subjectId":1,"id":1},{"firstName":"sonia","lastName":"sahay","subjectId":2,"id":2},{"firstName":"shreya","lastName":"sahay","subjectId":1,"id":3}],"subjects":[{"id":1,"name":"Devops"},{"id":2,"name":"SDET"}]}

For the above JSON you can use the below to fetch all the lastName

```
JsonPath abc = new JsonPath(res);
String deal = abc.getString("users.lastName");
System.out.println(deal);
```

Comment: Can you please add the code so that I can view it for my problem.

Comment: Rest Assured uses GPath so you will not be able to use [*] and have to code it as [0], or you could also use `.jsonPath().getString("weather.description");`

Comment: It works. Thanks. If I had a JSON where I have to choose all then how would I work on that.  What is the alternative for * in JsonPath.

Comment: For Example:{
  "users": [
    {
      "firstName": "sijo",
      "lastName": "john",
      "subjectId": 1,
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "firstName": "sonia",
      "lastName": "sahay",
      "subjectId": 2,
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "firstName": "shreya",
      "lastName": "sahay",
      "subjectId": 1,
      "id": 3
    }
  ],
  "subjects": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Devops"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "SDET"
    }
  ]
} If I want to choose all the lastName, then how would I choose that.

Comment: Glad I could help :)